# How to remove padding or space from react native drawer items

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I want to remove the left and right spaces from react native drawer items.. how can I do it ? i have tried below codes, but not working:

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName={Dashboard} screenOptions={{
                drawerActiveBackgroundColor: 'orange',
                drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                drawerInactiveTintColor: '#000',
                headerShown: false,

                sceneContainerStyle: {
                    padding: 0,
                    margin: 0,
                },
                drawerStyle: {
                    padding: 0,
                    margin: 0,
                },
                drawerLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            }}>
                <Drawer.Screen options={{
                    margin: 0,
                    width: '100%'
                }} name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

                <Drawer.Screen name="My Trips" component={Dashboard} />

                <Drawer.Screen name="Emergency Contacts" component={Dashboard} />

                <Drawer.Screen name="Saved Locations" component={Dashboard} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
```

[image]

Comment: which `react-navigation` version are you using?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Its version 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just dealing with this. You can do it in the drawerItemStyle in the screen options of the Navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator
   screenOptions={(navigation) => ({
      drawerItemStyle: {
         borderRadius: 0,
         width: '100%',
         marginLeft: 0
      }
  })}
>
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. this is what I wanted

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar

Answer (score 0):

Try using your custom component, we need to pass it in the `drawerContent` prop

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
  {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

More details [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/)